# asp.net mvc partial view is caching my model values

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, partial-views

I am working on an asp.net mvc web application. and i have a WebGrid, where i added a Page-size drop-down list to enable users to select how many records they like to have per page.

the Action method is:-

```
 [OutputCache(CacheProfile = "NoCache")]
 public ActionResult Disposed(string filter = null, int page = 1, int? pageSize = null, string sort = "Technology.Tag", string sortdir = "ASC")
        {
            GridList<DisposedResources> gridrecords = repository.GetDisposedResourcesForGrid(filter, page, pageSize, sort, sortdir, "rack");
            ViewBag.PagedSizeOptions = new PageOptions().FilterOptions;
            if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            {

                return PartialView("_disposed", gridrecords);
            }
            return View("Disposed", gridrecords);
        }
```

and here is the repository method :-

```
  public GridList<DisposedResources> GetDisposedResourcesForGrid(string filter, int page, int? pageSize, string sort, string sortdir, string resourcetype)
        {
            if (!pageSize.HasValue)
            {
                pageSize = Int32.Parse(System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TechPageSize"]);
            }

            var records = new GridList<DisposedResources>();
            records.currentfilter = filter;

            records.TotalRecords = GetDisposedResourcesForGridCount(filter, resourcetype);
            records.hasNetworkInfo = false;
            records.hasSystemInfo = false;
            records.CurrentPage = page;
            records.PageSize = pageSize.Value;
            records.currentsort = sort;
            records.currentsortdir = sortdir;
            records.Content = tms.DisposedResources.Include(a=>a.Technology).Where(x => (filter == null ||
                            (x.Technology.Tag.ToLower().StartsWith(filter.ToLower()))

                          ) && x.ResourceType.ToLower() == resourcetype.ToLower())
                    .OrderBy(sort + " " + sortdir)
                    .Skip((page - 1) * pageSize.Value)
                    .Take(pageSize.Value).ToList();
            return records;

        }
```

the Disposed view is :-

```
@model  S.ViewModels.GridList<S.Models.DisposedResources>




Show   @Html.DropDownList("FilterSize", new SelectList(ViewBag.PagedSizeOptions, "Value", "Text", ViewBag.pagesize ), new { @id= "FilterSize1",@class="SmallDropDown3"}) <span class="hidden-phone">per page.</span> 

<div id="disposed">

@Html.Partial( "_disposed",Model)

</div>

@section Scripts {



    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("body").on('change', '#FilterSize1', function () {

            //$(SizeProgressSort).show();
            $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
            $.ajax({
                type: "Get",
                url: '@Url.Action("Disposed")',

                data: { pageSize: $('#FilterSize1').val(), page: "1", sort: $('#currentsort').val(), sortdir: $('#currentsortdir').val() },

                success: successFunc,
                error: errorFunc
            });

            function successFunc(data, status) {

                $('#disposed').html(data);


            }

            function errorFunc() {
                alert('error');
            }
        });

    </script>
}
```

and the _disposed partial view is:-

```
@model  S.ViewModels.GridList<S.Models.DisposedResources>



        var gridcolumns = new List<WebGridColumn>();
        gridcolumns.Add(new WebGridColumn()
        {
            ColumnName = "Technology.Tag",
            Header = Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Content.FirstOrDefault().Technology.Tag).ToString(),
            CanSort = true
        });
       //code goes here...
            var grid = new WebGrid(
                        canPage: true,
                        rowsPerPage: Model.PageSize,
                        canSort: true,
                        ajaxUpdateContainerId: "grid");

            grid.Bind(Model.Content, rowCount: Model.TotalRecords, autoSortAndPage: false);
            grid.Pager(WebGridPagerModes.All);

            @grid.GetHtml(htmlAttributes: new { id = "grid" },   // id for ajaxUpdateContainerId parameter
            fillEmptyRows: false,
            tableStyle: "table table-bordered table-hover",
            mode: WebGridPagerModes.All,
            columns: gridcolumns

            );
            }
             </div></div></div>
<input type="hidden" value="@Model.currentsort" id="currentsort" /> @Model.currentsort
<input type="hidden" value="@Model.currentsortdir" id="currentsortdir" /> @Model.currentsortdir
```

the problem i am facing is that the two parameters; `currentsort + currentsortdir` which are being passed as part of the javascript will not be changed,and the user will loose the current sort order if he chose to chnage the page size drop down-list. so can anyone advice what is the problem, now even if i chose to display the two values:-

```
Model.currentsort

&

Model.currentsortdir
```

they will always have the defualt value, although these values are being changed inside the repository method... but seems the partial view is somehow caching the old values for these two parameter ?

Answer (score 8):

The ModelState is probably overriding the values you changed in your model. Call `ModelState.Clear()` in your action method and you should see the changed values.

Comment: ok i tried calling ModelState.Clear(); at the beginning of my action method ,, but did not solve the problem,, it is really strange !! could the webgrid causing this issue ?

Comment: i have a feeling that it is a bug inside Razor view, now i am using asp.net mvc 5.2.2 with Razor view version 3.0.0

Comment: After hours of trying to figure out why my page appeared to be caching even though I told it not too this worked,

Comment: I had some weird caching stuff going on, this fixed my issue after ages of me feeling utterly bamboozled. Thanks!

Comment: After a full day wasted this solved my issue.
I had some `select` tags in my partialview which I returned from an ajax request.
Strangly when creating my `select` tags manually no caching occured only when using the tag helpers. Razor Pages did some weird caching which I would not have expected.

Answer (score 0):

I know that you have done the cache setting through ajaxSetup but try putting cache:false inside your script and see if that makes a difference.

```
     $.ajax({
            cache: false
            type: "Get",
            url: '@Url.Action("Disposed")',
           --------
```

Comment: as i mentioned before , even when i am displaying the value inside my view (for example ; Model.currentsort & Model.currentsortdir),, i am getting the old values,, and they never chnage,, so there might be a caching problem in javascript ,, but currently even the Model values are not being updated..